# How to make Flask parse numbers in POSTed JSON data?

Tags: json, flask

When using `request.get_json()`, Flask creates a sort of `dict`, but doesn't parse the values. For example, if my JSON data is `{"name": "Joe", "age": "35"}`, I'd like Flask convert the `age` item to an `int` instead of a `str`.

How am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

You have to not quote the `35` in your JSON, see here:

```
import json

d = '{"name": "Joe", "age": "35"}' 
# The loads will not convert 35 to int, because it's quoted
json.loads(d)    # {u'age': u'35', u'name': u'Joe'}


d = '{"name": "Joe", "age": 35}' 
# The loads will convert 35 to int, because it's not quoted
json.loads(d)    # {u'age': 35, u'name': u'Joe'}
```

So, to answer your question, it's not Flask that's doing it, it is whatever is creating the JSON you pass to Flask.

Comment: Oh, I realize I misunderstood the `json.loads()` doc and examples. But the fact is that I don't know how to do a POST request with jQuery where the `data` isn't a string... Or maybe I've to do the post-processing to parse the result of `get_json()` by myself.

Comment: Well, the POST request with jQuery where the data isn't s string is a different question, so post that as a separate question.  The point is that the problem you want to fix is not with Flask, or Python at all really...